# How can I update config file with libconfig?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libconfig

How can I update config file with libconfig ?
**I want to update without removing other content of file**

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libconf

for example

```
RTL_test: {
  My_model : {
     tests = ["test1","test2","test3","test4"];
     ignore = ["test2"];
};
};

cfg['RTL_test']['My_model']['ignore']=''
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`libconf.dump(cfg, f)`](https://github.com/Grk0/python-libconf/blob/master/libconf.py#L618):

```
import libconf

# read
with open('example.cfg') as f:
  config = libconf.load(f)

config['RTL_test']['My_model']['ignore'] = 'updated'

# write
with open('example.cfg', 'w') as f:
  libconf.dump(config, f)
```

---

Other contents like comments get lost by design and it's not possible to preserve them without modifying the source of the `libconf` package. You may want to look for another package or solutions like writing your own serializer/deserializer.

Comment: But the example.cfg has other keys. when I do write the other keys are removed. I also want to save comments @Yannic Hamann

Comment: Please clarify and update your question. The only thing you are asking right now is how to update a config file. That's exactly what my code is doing.

Comment: Why ? I want to update without remove other content of file. @Yannic Hamann

Comment: The answer is: It is not possible without modifying the source of ``libconf`` the information is getting lost by design.

Comment: Only for a specific case, e.g. a static key or highly dynamic? If the latter would definitely be beyond the scope of a SO question. Anyways, asking about ``regex`` is a separate question since you are asking explicitly how to achieve that with ``libconf``.